# NetLogo: remove turtle given hamming distance

Tags: dictionary, netlogo, hamming-distance

Very new to NetLogo...
I have two breeds "vaccine" and "antibody". Each owns a string of symbols (e.g. ["A" "B" "C"]). I want the antibodies to remove the vaccine when they occupy the same space AND if at least 2/3 symbols match (latter is issue). I have been trying to use the 'map' function but cannot get it to work. Please Help! Here is what I have tried:

```
breed [vaccine vaccines]
breed [antibody antibodies]

vaccine-own [
  string2
  hamming-distance
]
antibody-own [
  string1
]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-antibody 10 [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set string1 n-values 3 [one-of["A" "B" "C"]]]
  create-vaccine 2 [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor set color red 
    set string2 n-values 3 [one-of["A" "B" "C"]] ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  move-antibody
  remove-antigen
  tick
end

to move-antibody
  ask antibody [
    right random 360
    forward 1
  ]
end

to remove-antigen
  ask vaccine [
    if any? other antibody-here [
      set hamming-distance (length remove true (map [?1 = ?2] string2 [string1] of myself))
      ]
    if any? other antibody-here with [hamming-distance > 1] [die]
  ] 
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `map` in this case is great! The way you combine `length`, `remove true` and `map` for calculating the Hamming distance shows a good understanding of these concepts.

Your problem is with the structure of your code. I think you should first define `hamming-distance` as a separate reporter, which will make the rest of the code easier to write:

```
to-report hamming-distance [ list1 list2 ]
  report length remove true (map [?1 = ?2] list1 list2)
end
```

If you test it in the command center, you will see that it works:

```
observer> show hamming-distance ["A" "B" "C"] ["A" "B" "B"]
observer: 1
observer> show hamming-distance ["A" "B" "C"] ["C" "C" "C"]
observer: 2
```

Once you have that, it's easy to write `remove-antigen` correctly:

```
to remove-antigen
  ask vaccines [
    if any? antibodies-here with [
      hamming-distance string1 [ string2 ] of myself <= 1
    ] [ die ]
  ]  
end
```

A few notes:

- you inverted plural and singular in your [`breed`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#breed) definitions. The plural always comes first. This way, you `ask vaccines` (i.e., all the vacinnes) instead of `ask vacinne` (which would be only one vacinne and doesn't make a lot of sense).
- to be able to define a `hamming-distance` reporter, you will need to remove the `hamming-distance` variable from `vaccines-own`; you don't need it anyway.
- in your original code, you asked the vacinnes to check for `other antibody-here`, but the use of [`other`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#other) was unnecessary since you were looking for members of a different breed.
- in your original code, I think you inverted `string1` and `string2`. In general, you should try to avoid calling variables `something1` and `something2` (unless it's in some very general code like the `hamming-distance` reporter I suggested above). Does the string represent DNA? Then call it `DNA`! And there is nothing wrong with two different breeds having a variable of the same name: don't append `1` and `2` if they represent the same thing.
- if you want the vaccine to die when 2/3 of the symbols are the same, you should check that the Hamming distance is `<= 1`, not `> 1`. Or even better, check that it is `<= (1 / 3) * length string1`.